# Mawaru Penguindrum Episode 16 seizon senkaryu Music

Tags: music, mawaru-penguindrum

what's the music played during seizon senryaku in Mawaru Penguindrum Episode 16?
I'm pretty sure it refers to something, but i can't find or remember

Comment: I don't have access to the episode right now, but the Wikipedia entry says that episode 16 uses "Rock Over Japan" like most of the Survival Strategy segments. Is it actually a different song?

Comment: yes, should have been more specific, it's not rock over Japan. it's when himari's taking pictures of the maid they use some special music.

Comment: Hmm, that makes it a little trickier since it's not listed as an insert song on that Wikipedia entry. I still haven't had a chance to check the episode, but I'll see if I can do that tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to track the song down - it's track 6 on the [1st OST disc](https://vgmdb.net/album/29729), called "sekushii ga kita!" (roughly "Sexy Has Come!", or "Here's sexy!"). As far as I can tell, it is only attributed to Yukari Hashimoto, the composer for the series soundtrack, and as such it doesn't seem to be a cover or direct reference like many of the insert songs in the show.

I can't find a preview of the song that I'm confident isn't a copyright violation, but it shouldn't be hard to find it by yourself.

Comment: You found it thx! i'll have to find the reference, it's probably an obscure french movie that inspired him, or maybe i'm wrong. Thank you!